# Make jquery function run on page load

Tags: jquery, function, opacity

I have a jquery function to change the opacity of an image on mouse hover to produce a pulsating effect, but I would like to change it so that the image pulsates as soon as the page loads, removing the mouse hover elements mouse over and mouse out.

Here is the code I have

```
    (function($) {
        $(document).ready(function() {
            window.pulse_image = null;
            window.pulse_continue_loop = false;

            $('.pulse_image').mouseover(function() {
            // User is hovering over the image.
            window.pulse_continue_loop = true;
            window.pulse_image = $(this);

            PulseAnimation(); // start the loop
        }).mouseout(function() {
            window.pulse_continue_loop = false;
            window.pulse_image.stop();
            window.pulse_image.css('opacity',1);
        });
    });
})(jQuery);


function PulseAnimation()
{
    var minOpacity = .33;
    var fadeOutDuration = 650;
    var fadeInDuration = 650;

    window.pulse_image.animate({
        opacity: minOpacity
    }, fadeOutDuration, function() {
        window.pulse_image.animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, fadeInDuration, function() {
            if(window.pulse_continue_loop) {
                PulseAnimation();
            }
        })
    });
}
```

From 
http://www.infinitywebcreations.com/2011/01/how-to-create-a-throbbingpulsing-image-effect-with-jquery/

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        window.pulse_image = $('.pulse_image');
        window.pulse_continue_loop = true;
        PulseAnimation(); // start the loop
    });
})(jQuery);​
```

Answer (score 13):

I don't see why you couldn't just remove the code relating to the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events.  If by "page load" you mean when the HTML document is loaded, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.pulse_image = $('.pulse_image');
    window.pulse_continue_loop = true;
    PulseAnimation();
});
```

If by "page load" you mean when all the images on a page have also loaded then try this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    window.pulse_image = $('.pulse_image');
    window.pulse_continue_loop = true;
    PulseAnimation();
});
```

The latter code example will wait until all images have finished loading.  This will trigger via the `window` being "loaded".  Rather, the first code example shows the `document` being ready which means that the document has been loaded, but not all the resources related to the document have as well.

Answer (score 3):

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    window.pulse_continue_loop = true;
    window.pulse_image = $('.pulse_image');
    PulseAnimation(); // start the loop
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

**Here is the way How I did it:**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert('Document Ready'); 
        $("#imgPreview").attr('src', '/Upload/Upload_Image.png');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to make that effect but one I figured out fastest is

```
 setTimeout(function(){
     $(".pulse_image").trigger('mouseover');
 }, 1300);
```

this is not the best solution for sure but it will do the "trick" ... just add this into `document.ready` callback.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a variation that loads default data with an ajax call when the page loads.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'include/ajax.php',
        data: $('#search_filters').serialize(),
        success: function (response) {
            $('#search_display').html(response);
        }
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    window.pulse_continue_loop = true;
    window.pulse_image = $('.pulse_image');
    setTimeout(function(){
      PulseAnimation();
    } // start the loop
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this way also.
this will trigger whenever your page is loading.

```
function pageLoad(sender,args) {
// call your function
}
```