# Django AJAX Search simplification/show all on page load

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, python-3.x, django-views

I have made a successful AJAX search box, but being fairly new, I was wondering if there was a better way to write this code. I am using `Python 3.6` and `Django 2`. Also, I want to display all entries on page load, which currently displays nothing. If I enter text and delete it, then all my entries show, but not on initial load. Thanks!

views.py

```
    def search_ajax(request):

        if request.method == 'POST':
            search_text = request.POST['search_text']
            if ',' in search_text:
                last,first = search_text.split(",")
                name_search = PhoneBook.objects.filter(last_name__istartswith=last.strip()
            ).filter(first_name__istartswith=first.strip())
            else:
                name_search = PhoneBook.objects.filter(last_name__istartswith=search_text.strip())

            phone_search = search = PhoneBook.objects.filter(number__icontains=search_text.strip())
            if search_text != "":
                search = list(chain(name_search, phone_search))[:10]
            else:
                search = list(chain(name_search, phone_search))
            print(search)
            context={'search':search,}
            html = render_to_string('search_ajax_results.html', context)
            return HttpResponse(html, content_type="application/json")
```

ajax_script.js

```
    $(function(){

        $('#search_ajax_input').keyup(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"search-ajax/",
            data:{
                'search_text': $('#search_ajax_input').val(),
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
            },
            success: searchSuccess,
            dataType: 'html'
        });
        });
    });

    function searchSuccess(data, textStatus,jqXHR)
    {
        $('#search-ajax-results').html(data);
    };
```

Comment: I think the missing part is to run search function on page load: [Make jquery function run on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468374/make-jquery-function-run-on-page-load). You may want to tag jquery so the people can provide answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Display all entries on page load**

Put the ajax call in a separate function and call it on keyup as well as on page load

ajax_script.js

```
$(function() {
    // perform search on page load
    search();
    $('#search_ajax_input').keyup(search);
});

function searchSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    $('#search-ajax-results').html(data);
};

function search() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "search-ajax/",
        data: {
            'search_text': $('#search_ajax_input').val(),
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
        },
        success: searchSuccess,
        dataType: 'html'
    });
}
```

**Better server side code**

This is not an extensive list, rather a few points to make your view more pythonic/less error prone

- Check for request.POST directly `if request.method == 'POST':` becomes `if request.POST:`
- To access dictionary values, use the get function to avoid KeyError `search_text = request.POST['search_text']` becomes `search_text = request.POST.get('search_text')`
- Follow [PEP 8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) e.g. Use either single or double quotations for your strings but be consistent about it, use a space after `,`, surround `=` with spaces when assigning variables but not when passing function kwargs, etc.
- To enhance code readability, use a positive check for the if condition `if search_text != "":` becomes `if search_text == "":` and switch the then and else blocks
- Python automatically evaluates empty string/zero/empty array/etc. to False meaning `if search_text:` is equivalent to `if search_text != "":`
- The variable search is set to either `list(chain(name_search, phone_search))` or `list(chain(name_search, phone_search))[:10]` depending on the if condition, so why do you give it a value in `phone_search = search = PhoneBook.objects.filter(number__icontains=search_text.strip())` before the if condition when you are going to overwrite it anyways?
- It would make slightly more sense in the template to use the name `results` or `search_results` to represent the results, just `search` can be slightly confusing.

Comment: Thanks. I will make adjustments accordingly when I get some time.